# Is there an Android equivalent to XInput?

Tags: android, xbox360

I'm basically curious as to how support for the Xbox 360 controller is implemented in Android?

Is there a way to fire specific functions/commands *to* the paired controller when using it with Android? This functionality is possible on Windows using the functions contained within xinput, but is there some similar library on Android?